# What is the definition of "excessive"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, common-word

I am really confused.

From dictionary.com, excessive means going before the usual or necessary.

So does "excessive comforts" mean too many comforts, more than what is necessary, or equal to "too many comforts (all of it) - the necessary part."

If this sounds confusing, here is an analogy using a cup of water:
[image]

Comment: Yes.  And to be sure I have an excessive number of characters, yes again.

Comment: ("Excess" means simply "more than enough".  "Excessive", on the other hand, often is used to imply excess to the point of waste or indulgence.)

Comment: @HotLicks, so both you mean? Then wouldn't it be confusing?

Comment: "going **beyond** the usual, necessary, or proper limit or degree".

Comment: I just uploaded an illustration. From my experience, "excess" is the extra. But not sure about "excessive". Does it describe the extra, orthe whole thing?

Comment: So like saying excessive water as in too much water? Or the part that I don't need only?

Comment: The water that you don't need is indeed the *excess*.  If you include the excess water where it is not needed, it is *excessive*.  One is a noun, the other an adjective.

Comment: Excess detail is detail over and above what is *necessary*, which simply implies it ***could*** be omitted. Excessive detail is beyond what is *desirable*, so by implication it ***should*** be omitted.

Comment: @phoog, this realllllyyy help

Answer (score 1):

"Excessive" means more of something than what is needed, yes. "Excessive comforts" means someone has access to many luxuries, and the speaker is wondering why someone would need so much material wealth.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the confusion is the context in which you're trying to make the word make sense. Consider "excessive force" or "excessive drinking"--it means more than is desired or appropriate. There is no such thing as "excessive comforts", except in special contexts like "Spartan warriors were forbidden excessive comforts".

Comment: As your examples show, there is a moral quality to "excessive". The implication is that someone disapproves of the level to which the thing being so described has risen -- the law in the first case, society in the second, and the Spartans in the third.

Answer (score 0):

**excess** (*noun or adj.*) vs **excessive** (*adj.*):

**excess** (*singular or uncountable noun*):

an amount that is more than acceptable, expected, or reasonable (**too much**)

> *'An excess **of** enthusiasm is not always a good thing.'*
>
> *'They eat **to** excess.'* (= too much)
>
> *'There will be an increase in tax for those earning **in** excess **of*** (=more than) *twice the national average wage.'*

**excess** (*adj.*):

extra

> *'Cut off any excess pastry and put it to one side.'*

Source: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/excess)

**excessive** (*adj.*):

too much

> *'Excessive exercise can sometimes cause health problems.'*
>
> *'The film was criticised for its excessive violence and nudity.'*

Source: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/excessive?q=Excessive)

The given example of the cup of water has 'excess' being used as a noun. 'Excess water' and 'excessive water' would be the adjectival forms. It is usual to see 'excess' as a noun, when referring to the amount or degree by which one thing exceeds another.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking whether "excessive comforts" refers to just the portion of 'comforts' beyond the necessary, or whether it refers to the whole lot of 'comforts'. Others have provided definitions, so I won't repeat them here.

Let's consider a parallel construction that deals with something more accessible:

> He was driving with excessive speed.

Suppose the speed limit was 60km/h and he drove at 100km/h. The speed referenced in the sentence above would be 100km/h, made in the context of the 60km/h limit. The excess speed would be the difference, 40km/h.

Note that for 'comforts', it isn't always easy to identify a tangible portion of something and call it *necessary*. For example, one might consider owning a solid-gold toilet bowl to be *excessive comfort*, but if you removed enough of it to reduce it to the price of a porcelain toilet bowl, the remainder wouldn't be considered to even meet 'normal' comfort levels.

In answer to your question, "excessive comforts" **refers to the whole**, given some contextual definition of normality or need. It doesn't refer to just the portion beyond that normality or need.

Answer (score -1):

Excessive means too much. This meaning can be found in any dictionary.

I also like to learn the opposite meaning of any word; it helps me to know how both words should be used.

Comment: Hi, Moh. Welcome to EL&U. Please be careful with capitalization and typo when you write an answer. We don't encourage an answer without reference or research and you would know if you compare your answer with that of Julie Carter. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Please incorporate a definition from one of the dictionaries you mention, along with a sample sentence to illustrate how the word is used.  Find a good answer to model your answer on.